# Scraping profiles with Python and the "scrape-linkedin" package

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `scrape_linkedin` [package](https://github.com/austinoboyle/scrape-linkedin-selenium). I follow the section on the github page on how to set up the package/LinkedIn `li_at` key (which I paste here for clarity).

```
Getting LI_AT
Navigate to www.linkedin.com and log in
Open browser developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I or right click -> inspect element)
Select the appropriate tab for your browser (Application on Chrome, Storage on Firefox)
Click the Cookies dropdown on the left-hand menu, and select the www.linkedin.com option
Find and copy the li_at value
```

Once I collect the `li_at` value from my LinkedIn, I run the following code:

```
from scrape_linkedin import ProfileScraper

with ProfileScraper(cookie='myVeryLong_li_at_Code_which_has_characters_like_AQEDAQNZwYQAC5_etc') as scraper:
    profile = scraper.scrape(url='https://www.linkedin.com/in/justintrudeau/')
print(profile.to_dict())
```

I have two questions (I am originally an R user).

1. How can I input a list of profiles:

   https://www.linkedin.com/in/justintrudeau/

   https://www.linkedin.com/in/barackobama/

   https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/

   https://www.linkedin.com/in/wozniaksteve/

and scrape the profiles? (In R I would use the `map` function from the `purrr` package to apply the function to each of the LinkedIn profiles).

2. The output (from the original github page) is returned in a JSON style format. My second question is how I can convert this into a pandas data frame (i.e. it is returned similar to the following).

> {'personal_info': {'name': 'Steve Wozniak', 'headline': 'Fellow at
> Apple', 'company': None, 'school': None, 'location': 'San Francisco
> Bay Area', 'summary': '', 'image': '', 'followers': '', 'email': None,
> 'phone': None, 'connected': None, 'websites': [],
> 'current_company_link': 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/sandisk/'},
> 'experiences': {'jobs': [{'title': 'Chief Scientist', 'company':
> 'Fusion-io', 'date_range': 'Jul 2014 – Present', 'location': 'Primary
> Data', 'description': "I'm looking into future technologies applicable
> to servers and storage, and helping this company, which I love, get
> noticed and get a lead so that the world can discover the new amazing
> technology they have developed. My role is principally a marketing one
> at present but that will change over time.", 'li_company_url':
> 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/sandisk/'}, {'title': 'Fellow',
> 'company': 'Apple', 'date_range': 'Mar 1976 – Present', 'location': '1
> Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 94015', 'description': 'Digital Design
> engineer.', 'li_company_url': ''}, {'title': 'President & CTO',
> 'company': 'Wheels of Zeus', 'date_range': '2002 – 2005', 'location':
> None, 'description': None, 'li_company_url':
> 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/wheels-of-zeus/'}, {'title':
> 'diagnostic programmer', 'company': 'TENET Inc.', 'date_range': '1970
> – 1971', 'location': None, 'description': None, 'li_company_url':
> ''}], 'education': [{'name': 'University of California, Berkeley',
> 'degree': 'BS', 'grades': None, 'field_of_study': 'EE & CS',
> 'date_range': '1971 – 1986', 'activities': None}, {'name': 'University
> of Colorado Boulder', 'degree': 'Honorary PhD.', 'grades': None,
> 'field_of_study': 'Electrical and Electronics Engineering',
> 'date_range': '1968 – 1969', 'activities': None}], 'volunteering':
> []}, 'skills': [], 'accomplishments': {'publications': [],
> 'certifications': [], 'patents': [], 'courses': [], 'projects': [],
> 'honors': [], 'test_scores': [], 'languages': [], 'organizations':
> []}, 'interests': ['Western Digital', 'University of Colorado
> Boulder', 'Western Digital Data Center Solutions', 'NEW Homebrew
> Computer Club', 'Wheels of Zeus', 'SanDisk®']}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You can create a custom function to scrape data and use `map` function in Python to apply it over each profile link.

Secondly, to create a pandas dataframe using a dictionary, you can simply pass the dictionary to pd.DataFrame.

Thus to create a dataframe `df`, with dictionary `dict`, you can do like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```